# RESTful: What is the equivalent of Spring's @RequestParam and @RequestPart in Jersey?

Tags: spring, rest, jersey

What is the equivalent of Spring's following annotations in Jersey?

- `@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam`
- `@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestPart`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Jersey's equivalent of Spring's `@RequestParam` is [`@QueryParam`](https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/nonav/2.0/apidocs/javax/ws/rs/QueryParam.html).

For multi-part data use the [`MultiPart`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.11/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/media/multipart/MultiPart.html) class or [`@FormDataParam`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.11/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/media/multipart/FormDataParam.html) annotation.

Additional info at:

- https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/jaxrs-resources.html#d0e1905
- https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html#d0e7924